# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /SimulWS/services/Simulation and the WSA Action = null

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis

I'm trying to access my web service via a browser but each time I'm having the exception bellow . 
I'm using WebSphere 7 with `axis2`, didn't have this problem with the `was6`.

I'm trying to access it with :
`http://localhost:9083/SimulWS/services/Simulation.SimulationHttpSoap12Endpoint/`

WSDL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://wsCall.loans.service" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ax23="http://util.java/xsd" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:ax21="http://model.simulation.service/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://wsCall.loans.service" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

  <wsdl:documentation> Simulateur de Crédit </wsdl:documentation>
  -
  <wsdl:types>
    -
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://util.java/xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
      -
      <xs:complexType name="Properties">
        <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:schema>
   -
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://wsCall.loans.service" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:ax24="http://util.java/xsd" xmlns:ax22="http://model.simulation.service/xsd">
      <xs:import namespace="http://model.simulation.service/xsd" />
      <xs:import namespace="http://util.java/xsd" /> -
      <xs:element name="simulate">
        -
       <xs:complexType>
          -
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="montant" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="duree" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="taux" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="dureeFranchise" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
     -
      <xs:element name="simulateResponse">
       -
 <xs:complexType>
         -
 <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="ax21:OutputModel" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      -
     <xs:element name="readProperties">
        -
 <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      -
     <xs:element name="readPropertiesResponse">
        -
        <xs:complexType>
          -
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="ax23:Properties" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    -
    <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://model.simulation.service/xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
      -
<xs:complexType name="OutputModel">
        -
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="body" type="ax21:BodyOutput" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="error" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="header" type="ax21:HeaderOutput" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      -
      <xs:complexType name="BodyOutput">
        -
        <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="bodyRows" type="xs:anyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      -
     <xs:complexType name="HeaderOutput">
       -
      <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="accessoires" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="assurance" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="cdDevice" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="cdTerm" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="crdu" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="dTech" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="echeance" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="interets" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="sommeCapital" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="sommeCrd" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="stdu" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  -
  <wsdl:message name="simulateRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:simulate" />
  </wsdl:message>
  -
 <wsdl:message name="simulateResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:simulateResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  -
 <wsdl:message name="readPropertiesRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:readProperties" />
  </wsdl:message>
  -
  <wsdl:message name="readPropertiesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:readPropertiesResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  -
  <wsdl:portType name="SimulationPortType">
   -
   <wsdl:operation name="simulate">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:simulate" message="ns:simulateRequest" />

      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:simulateResponse" message="ns:simulateResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
   -
    <wsdl:operation name="readProperties">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:readProperties" message="ns:readPropertiesRequest" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:readPropertiesResponse" message="ns:readPropertiesResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  -
  <wsdl:binding name="SimulationSoap11Binding" type="ns:SimulationPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> -
    <wsdl:operation name="simulate">
      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:simulate" /> -
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      -
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    -
   <wsdl:operation name="readProperties">
      <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:readProperties" /> -
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      -
     <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  -
  <wsdl:binding name="SimulationSoap12Binding" type="ns:SimulationPortType">
    <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> -
    <wsdl:operation name="simulate">
      <soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:simulate" /> 
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
     -
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    -
   <wsdl:operation name="readProperties">
      <soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:readProperties" /> -
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
     -
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
 -
  <wsdl:binding name="SimulationHttpBinding" type="ns:SimulationPortType">
    <http:binding verb="POST" /> -
    <wsdl:operation name="simulate">
      <http:operation location="simulate" /> -
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters" />
      </wsdl:input>
      -
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    -
    <wsdl:operation name="readProperties">
      <http:operation location="readProperties" /> -
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters" />
      </wsdl:input>
      -
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  -
  <wsdl:service name="Simulation">
    -
    <wsdl:port name="SimulationHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:SimulationSoap11Binding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:9083/SimulWS/services/Simulation.SimulationHttpSoap11Endpoint/" />
    </wsdl:port>
   -
    <wsdl:port name="SimulationHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:SimulationSoap12Binding">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:9083/SimulWS/services/Simulation.SimulationHttpSoap12Endpoint/" />
    </wsdl:port>
    -
    <wsdl:port name="SimulationHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:SimulationHttpBinding">
      <http:address location="http://localhost:9083/SimulWS/services/Simulation.SimulationHttpEndpoint/" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @Ivan i will try to be more specific